# OpenShift deployment - pod console logs are truncated

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-3

we are using OpenShift container platform (v3.11) for hosting our java application. We are writing application logs to standard pod console. However when I try to view pod logs or try to save logs to file, I am not getting complete log file instead getting only partial log (looks logs are truncated). I have tried to provide different options while viewing logs (like --since=48h etc..), but none of them worked.

Is there any way I can increase pod console buffer size or write complete log file contents to file.

Answer (score 1):

The better way is configuring log aggrigation via fluentd/elastic (see [elk_logging](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/aggregate_logging.html)), however there's an option to change docker log driver settings on the node with the running container (see [managing_docker_container_logs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/host_preparation.html#managing-docker-container-logs) or [docker_logging_configure](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/))